# Not able to run scripts in android device using appium

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to execute scripts in android devices. Page/tab crashes in middle of execution. Please see the attachment.

OS: Windows 8
Appium Version: 1.3.5
Chromedriver version: 2.15
Device: Samsng S3
Selenium server standalone jar: 2.45

I Keep getting this error in cmd:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origVa
:"unknown error: session deleted because of page crash\nfrom tab crashed\n

Thanks in advance.

```
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/element/0.2412
46007739007-17/click 200 593.414 ms - 72
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/element {"usin
:"xpath","value":"//meta[@content=\"BuyPath/Payment\"]"}
info: [debug] Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: [debug] Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/
b/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/element","method":"POST","json":{"u
ng":"xpath","value":"//meta[@content=\"BuyPath/Payment\"]"}}
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message"
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValu
:"unknown error: session deleted because of page crash\nfrom tab crashed\n  (S
sion info: chrome=43.0.2357.78)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d6
c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)"},"sessio
d":"7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/element 500 25
.368 ms - 391
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/screenshot {}
info: [debug] Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: [debug] Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/
b/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/screenshot","method":"GET"}
info: [debug] Proxied response received with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"7e9
c59f81517437505fec42a63833c\",\"status\":6,\"value\":{\"message\":\"no such se
ion\\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa0960
e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)\"}}"
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c/screenshot 200
.186 ms - 214
info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/7e9c2c59f81517437505fec42a63833c {}
info: Shutting down appium session
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"OK, shutting dow
,"status":0}
```

Comment: We need more information in order to be able to help. Please provide your script code. Please provide full error stack.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesAndroid = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),
    capabilitiesAndroid);

Comment: These are the capabilities set. Script code is normal using sendkeys & action class. I enter all the details in my application[shipping page] & when I click on proceed to billing, page loads & crashes. Code works fine in Samsung S3 in windows 7 system but not in windows 8.